# How do you change the Hugepagesize?

Tags: linux, memory

How can I change the pagesize for Hugepages on Linux?  I'd like to increase it to 4096 kB or 8192 kB. I'm working specifically with Centos and Amazon Linux.

```
$ grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Comment: Here is how you can change it in AWS.. However no other options were supported for the instances I were using: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hugepagesize value is set at boot time.  But you cannot set it to an arbitrary value: the set of possible values is determined by the CPU architecture.

Further reading:

- [Kernel Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt) says

> Some platforms support multiple huge page sizes.  To allocate huge pages
>   of a specific size, one must precede the huge pages boot command parameters
>   with a huge page size selection parameter `"hugepagesz=<size>"`.   must
>   be specified in bytes with optional scale suffix `[kKmMgG]`.  The default huge
>   page size may be selected with the `"default_hugepagesz=<size>"` boot parameter.

- [Kernel Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

> **`default_hugepagesz=`**
>   [same as **`hugepagesz=`**] The size of the default
>   HugeTLB page size. This is the size represented by
>   the legacy `/proc/` hugepages APIs, used for SHM, and
>   default size when mounting hugetlbfs filesystems.
>   Defaults to the default architecture's huge page size
>   if not specified.
>
> **`hugepagesz=`**  [HW,IA-64,PPC,X86-64]
>  The size of the HugeTLB pages.    On x86-64 and powerpc, this option can be specified
>   multiple times interleaved with `hugepages=` to reserve
>   huge pages of different sizes. Valid pages sizes on
>   x86-64 are **2M** (when the CPU supports `"pse"`) and **1G**
>   (when the CPU supports the `"pdpe1gb"` cpuinfo flag).

- [Hugepages](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages) (Debian, but applicable)
- [Huge pages part 3: Administration](https://lwn.net/Articles/376606/) (shows examples of huge pages boot parameters)

Some users have reported problems with Hugepagesize in AWS:

- [Hugepages Crashes Oracle DB on a EC2 instrance running Oracle Linux 6](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=477265)
- [Linux HugePages for Oracle on Amazon EC2](https://www.pythian.com/blog/linux-hugepages-for-oracle-on-amazon-ec2-possible-but-not-convenient-easy-or-fully-supported/)

Bear in mind that it is a hardware-dependent feature, and may not work for your configuration.

Comment: Any idea if this is possible in AWS?